# Chinese text in English scrbook with luatexja-fontspec and polyglossia

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, chinese

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
%\setotherlanguage{chinese}
\usepackage{xstring}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\newfontfamily\chinesefont[Path=/usr/share/fonts/arphicfonts/]{UMing}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

The common transliteration of 易经 is {\enquote{I Ching,}} 
following the now-obsolete Wade-Giles system: modern Romanization 
of almost all modern Chinese texts follows the Hanyu Pinyin standard used here. 
See [huang].

\end{document}
```

When I try to typeset it, the second Chinese character does not typeset correctly (I get a box with an X in it). This is not the only instance where a character fails to be typeset corretcly. If I uncomment the line for ctex, the Chinese renders correctly, but all the English is typeset wrong. As far as I know, polyglossia does not support Chinese. I have a large document with a lot of brief snippets of Chinese and Japanese text, but the main document language is English (other languages include polytonic Greek, French, Latin, Italian, Russian, and, uh … "voynich"). I was told that lualatex was better at typesetting multiple languages, but I can't get this to work. Suggestions?

Comment: if you can't get `polyglossia` to work, you may consider `babel`. See https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/news-guides/guides/useful-links-to-tex.stackexchange.md .

Comment: It's nearly 500 pages of text, with thousands of quotes in other languages. I'd really like to avoid having to switch them all to babel's markup if at all possible.

Comment: Babel has a `\babeltags` command that adds support for Polyglossia's text-selection commands, e.g. `\textchinese`. Also, Babel  in LuaLaTeX can auto-detect what script you type in, so you might not need to tag languages at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `\tracinglostchars=2` to your preamble (or search the `.log` file), you’ll see the warning message,

```
Missing character: There is no 经 (U+7ECF)
in font file:HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf:jfm=ujis!
```

This comes from trying to use `polyglossia` commands with `luatexja-fontspec`.  You wanted to set `\chinesefont` to UMing.  However, `lualatex-ja` does not use `\chinesefont`, and you don’t tag the text as Chinese for Polyglossia.  So, you get the default font from `luatexja-fontspec`.  This is a Japanese font, so it contains only those Chinese characters that happen to share codepoints with *kanji*.

There are multiple ways to resolve this.  If you want to use `luatexja-fontspec`, you should use its commands to select the CJK font, `\setmainjfont`, `\newjfontfamily`, etc.  Also set an English text if you don’t want a package overriding the defaults.

Your TeX installation should also be able to find any font in a subdirectory of `\usr\share\fonts\` without a `Path=` argument.  I recommend against putting an absolute `Path=` in your document, since this will give you a document that will not compile on any other computer.  Also, there are multiple font faces in `uming.ttc`, and you should specify which you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[match]{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\setotherlanguage{chinese}
\usepackage{xstring}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX,
                      Scale=MatchUppercase }

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale=1.0]
\setmainjfont{AR PL UMing TW}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\begin{document}

The common transliteration of 易经 is {\enquote{I Ching,}} 
following the now-obsolete Wade-Giles system: modern Romanization 
of almost all modern Chinese texts follows the Hanyu Pinyin standard used here. 
See [huang].

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Roman / UMing TW sample]

To use `ctex` rather than `luatexja-fontspec`, use its commands to set the CJK fonts, *i.e.* `\newCJKmainfont`.  It doesn’t play well with `csquotes`, so you might be forced to `\DeclareQuoteStyle`.

To stick with `polyglossia` and use `\chinesefont`, you would want to add language tagging, *e.g.* `\textchinese{易经}`.  In XeLaTeX, you could configure `ucharclasses` to automatically tag Chinese characters as Chinese for you.

Finally, you could use `babel`.  It does not support all the features of `ctex` or `luatexja`, but it suffices to insert words and short phrases, written horizontally.  Unlike `luatexja` or `ctex`, it supports multiple ideographic writing systems in the same document.

You mention in the comments that you have a lot of text already tagged for `polyglossia` and dread changing it.  You can configure `babel` to support `polyglossia` user commands, such as `\textenglish`, and also to auto-detect which script you’re typing in so you don’t need to tag many languages at all.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\setotherlanguage{chinese}
\usepackage{xstring}

\babelprovide[import=zh-hant, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}
% Or import=zh-hans for Simplified Chinese.

\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX,
                      Scale=MatchUppercase }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}
          [Renderer=HarfBuzz]{AR PL Uming TW}

% Enable \textenglish, \begin{english}, etc.
\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{chinese=chinese}

\begin{document}

The common transliteration of 易经 is {\enquote{I Ching,}} 
following the now-obsolete Wade-Giles system: modern Romanization 
of almost all modern Chinese texts follows the Hanyu Pinyin standard used here. 
See [huang].

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Roman / UMing TW sample]

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I dropped the paths from those font specifications (though that does seem to make compilation take longer), and added the "j" in the middle. Now it reads `\newjfontfamily\chinesefont{Noto Serif CJK TC}` and appears to work fine when I enclose Chinese characters with `\textchinese{}`. Since Polyglossia supports all the other languages I use, I enclose all the rest with `\begin{language}****\end{language}` environments. One other question: Can you code languages in section titles? It doesn't seem to work (ie, `\chapter{\begin{german}Hörspiel\end{german}}` fails).